# how to use Auto-render (KaTeX 0.9.0-alpha) in brower?

Tags: javascript, katex

I created a single `index.html` file to test auto-render of KaTeX (0.9.0-alpha).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha/katex.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="el"><span>$$2+\frac{1}{x}$$</span></div>
    <script>
        renderMathInElement(document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open html file in browser (Chrome 61.0), I got an error (also appears in KaTeX 0.8.3):
`Uncaught TypeError: renderMathInElement is not a function`

So how to use KaTex in a single html?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are hitting a bug in KaTeX: https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/920. The bug has been fixed but the fix is not yet released to the CDN, so in the meantime I just reverted to 0.8.3; I am surprised that did not work for you.